# Civ 5 crashes on startup

Tags: linux, steam, manjaro

I have a fresh install of civilization 5 in steam but when I start it, I get a black screen then an instant crash.  I'm seeing this error in terminal:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
```

I am using Manjaro linux and installed this through the steam client, however it mentions ubuntu in that folder...

Here is the full output when the game is run:

```
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to SynchronizingCloud with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to ProcessingShaderCache with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to SiteLicenseSeatCheckout with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to CreatingProcess with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp waiting for user response to CreatingProcess ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp continues with user response "CreatingProcess"
Opted-in Controller Mask: 30
Game update: AppID 8930 "", ProcID 6920, IP 0.0.0.0:0
>>> Adding process 6920 for game ID 8930
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to WaitingGameWindow with ""
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to Completed with ""
>>> Adding process 6921 for game ID 8930
Game update: AppID 8930 "", ProcID 6921, IP 0.0.0.0:0
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 8930
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198017115478 [API loaded no]
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(20180608222225)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Game removed: AppID 8930 "", ProcID 6921 
No cached sticky mapping in ActivateActionSet.Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1528497815)
```

Comment: What is your GPU and have you installed any libraries for your GPU?

Comment: Nvidia GeForce GTX1060.  In Manjaro settings manager it shows that I have `video-nvidia-390xx` and `video-linux` installed for the GPU.  I am getting the exact same thing on my laptop with a 4-year-old Nvidia GPU too.

Comment: (using proprietary drivers)

Comment: How did you install this?  Stuff that isn't in the Manjaro or Arch repo often needs to be compiled.

Comment: Through the steam client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that worked for me, as suggested by a user on Steam Discussion was the following:

```
LD_PRELOAD='./libcxxrt.so:/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6:/usr/lib32/libopenal.so.1' %command%
```

Answer (score 17):

I had this same problem on Manjaro, game worked fine but started to crash on startup with this same error message after a system update. Apparently this was caused by pulse audio upgrading to version 12.0. Adding

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libopenal.so.1 %command%
```

in the launch options fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Note: This also requires a package (lib32-openal) to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using steam client beta, add `./Civ5XP "%command%"` (keep the quotes as they are) in `Set Launch Options` in the game properties tab in steam library.

Also, this error does not cause the crash, and is ignored by steam. What causes the crash is probably the apostrophe (') in the game directory filename. See if there is an "unexpected EOF" in the log /steam output, in which case the above workaround applies. This is a bug in the steam client beta.

Comment: I just tried this but the same thing happens.  Also, I'm not using the beta client update.  I just added the complete terminal output for steam when civ is run in case that helps.

Comment: Restart steam in a terminal and right after the crash post output starting from the line ">>> Adding process 5225 for game ID *******" to "Game removed: AppID *****"  - Your output may vary.

Comment: Meanwhile you can also disable in-game steam overlay from the game properties if you have not tried it: uncheck `Enable the Steam Overlay while in-game`

Comment: I uncheck that in-game because the game won't even launch.  As in my question, it instantly crashes.

Comment: Have you unchecked it in the properties menu in the steam library?

Comment: Oh I see - just tried that and it still didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running from the steam library with this as launch option in the game properties menu: `./Civ5XP "LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libxcb.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libgpg-error.so ./libcxxrt.so /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6' %command%"`

Comment: Still doesn't work.  Also, my `/usr/$LIB/`folder does not have a `libgcc_s.so.1` file, just `bin`, `include`, `lib`, `lib32`, `lib64`, `local`, `sbin`, `share`, `src` folders/files

Comment: what versions of `libxcb.so` do you have? What does the steam terminal log say about the crash with the launch options? Also make sure to launch the game from the library.

Comment: Also is steam-runtime enabled?